# How to modify the ChoiceBox checkmark in JavaFX?

Tags: java, css, javafx-8

First of all, is it even possible to modify the ChoiceBox checkmark shape? Completely altering the CheckBox mark was easy enough using the CSS class (`.check-box:selected .mark`). However, all that I've found online for the ChoiceBox's ContextMenu's mark is that you can modify its color using `-fx-mark-color` within the `.context-menu` CSS class. I've tried several classnames to change the shape to a custom SVG to no avail.

```
.context-menu .menu-item:selected .mark {
    -fx-shape: "M1,1 h4 v4 h-4 v-4 Z";
}
```

In the following picture I've completely reskinned my JavaFX application to match Mac's native Cocoa GUI, but the menu checkmark is the only flaw that appears to be impossible to fix.

[image]

Comment: The `-fx-shape` is an SVG string, did you try supplying a different SVG string?

Comment: @jewelsea Yes. I included that attempt in my post. It doesn't work; I also know that it is a valid shape SVG because I tried it on the `.arrow-button`, which is alterable.

Comment: Edit your question to include the actual SVG string you used rather than an unusable value like `<SVG String>`.

Comment: I don't have time to look at this in more detail right now, but refer to the [default modena.css stylesheet](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u60/rt/file/tip/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css#l769), where the CSS path to the checkbox mark is: `.check-box > .box > .mark` or `.check-box:indeterminate  > .box > .mark`, depending on checkbox pseudo-state.

Comment: @jewelsea I said I've already managed to overhaul the CheckBox mark. What I'm asking is how to similarly customize the MenuItem checkmark, like the one in the picture.

Comment: Sorry Sam I wasn't paying enough question when reading your question.  Search the modena.css stylesheet for `-fx-shape`, you will find: `.check-menu-item:checked > .left-container > .check`.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I have taken a look at the style sheet defaults before but they were overwhelmingly big. Also I couldn't find anything about it no matter how much I searched.

Comment: @jewelsea If you make your comment into an answer I will choose it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search the [modena.css](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u60/rt/file/tip/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css#l769) stylesheet for [`-fx-shape`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region).  For Java 8, You will find:

```
.check-menu-item:checked > .left-container > .check
```

This is the CSS selector for checkmarks inside menu items (it also covers checks for selected items in a ChoiceBox).  Define the same CSS selection path in a custom CSS stylesheet.  Inside that selector, place a `-fx-shape` rule that defines a custom svg path for the shape you wish to use for checks.

Comment: Selected item in a ChoiceBox could also be covered with .radio-menu-item:checked > .left-container > .radio selector